# Why Muslims can't live in peace with the rest of the world?

Tags: non-muslim-countries

I don't want to look hateful, but I don't think Muslims should be tolerated in any modern and civilized society, they want to kill gays and force people to live like they live and this is something that us (the civilized people) should not accept not even under "freedom of religion" (something that I don't think Muslims understand).

We didn't evolve to support individual rights and freedom of speech and religion just so Muslims can come and think they can impose their views on us abusing our own freedom.

So I want to know why Muslims are like this? It's the only religion that still generate terrorists today and why should the rest of the world allow this? Aren't your faith to your God enough to you?

If you think your God will punish the people why do you feel the necessity to judge in the name of your God? Let him punish when the time comes.

I'm asking this because in many places you can see so much Muslims trying to convince people that "Islam is a religion of peace" but yeah, the only religion that still throw gays out of buildings, burn people alive and form like 99% of terrorist groups around the world and their religions seems aim to conquer all the world and make every woman wear hijab or die trying.

Some Muslims truly believe one day they will make the whole world fall under sharia law (and they have the audacity to try do that in London... http://www.gatestoneinstitute.org/3555/sharia-law-london ) but if they ever start a third world war they will just be nuked...

So tell me Islam is a religion of peace, but their followers cannot be?

Comment: I suggest you learn more about the history before making judgments (hint: compare how Muslims societies lived/living before and after the western societies invaded and occupied all of their lands).

Comment: http://quran.com/42/37-43 and the rest are rules...... And.... a few people today are not following the rules I can say... unfortunately.

Comment: I don't want to look hateful, but I don't think people like you should be tolerated in any modern and civilized society, they want to forbid other people to live there, and force people to live like they live and this is something that us (the civilized people) should not accept not even under "freedom of speech" (something that I don't think you understand).

Comment: Unfortunately, many people out there form corrupted image on Islam as a whole just because of a few stupid people out there calling themselves and their actions Islamic. People, plz don't do this. There are still [~1.8 Billion Muslims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_populations#Adherent_estimates) out there trying their best to follow correct Islam. **Plz don't judge based on the actions of a few.**

Comment: Actually I can forbid other people to live in my land, because it's my land, so yeah i can forbid you to come here and think you can stone gays or tell the woman to wear hijab, and believe me and thousand of others will not get rest until Islam is forbidden in our countries, Muslims are not welcome in non-muslims countries  and never will, we will not give you a job, our intelligence agencies will spy on you 24 hours on everything you do and if you say "jihad" you will suffer the consequences

Comment: We are not a site for argument and debate (see http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/1255/22); from this question and your behaviour in comments, it's obvious you're less interested in actually asking a practical and answerable question, and just here to rant and argue: This sort of behaviour is wholly unacceptable here.

Comment: this is completely opinionated question without any factual base

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser I could answer this using the Quran so how is this off topic?

Comment: @Bleeding Fingers How is it off topic? An answer can be given within the realm of Islam and then state that the Muslim Culture part is a separate subject...

Comment: @goldPseudo Why not flag the arguments instead of the questions?

Comment: @jason There are a lot of questions the Stack Exchange model simply is npt designed to handle; curating questions so that those that *do* work stand out is an integral aspect of the SE philosophy. If you wish to discuss site policy or dispute an action taken on any post, please take it to [meta]; that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately it appears as if you've been misled by an ahistorical and selective reading of current events. Almost every generalized assertion you make in your question is demonstrably false.

- There is no dichotomy between the Muslim world and the modern and civilized world. One in five people in the world today is Muslim; Muslim countries as a whole are productive members of the globe, integrated in every way possible with the global system. Visit Malaysia, Turkey, Morocco, etc. and see for yourself.
- Islam doesn't force anyone to live like Muslims. In fact, in Islamic societies, Christians, Jews, fire-worshippers, Hindus, and others are permitted to live by their own laws, have their own places of worship, and so on.
- Understanding freedom of religion: see previous point. There is [no compulsion on anyone to become Muslim](http://quran.com/2/256), *even* in an Islamic state.
- Muslims as a whole don't seek to impose their views on anyone else, individual acts by misguided people notwithstanding (e.g. the Charlie Hebdo incident). There is no prescription in Islam for this.
- Islam (or any religion really) doesn't generate terrorists. Geopolitical conditions on the ground do. See [Christian militias in CAR](http://www.aljazeera.com/news/africa/2015/01/un-muslims-ethnically-cleansed-car-2015196546788288.html) and the [terrorist Buddhist monk](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-30930997). Also look up LTTE. In all these cases, I would be misguided to attribute the actions of these people to Christianity, Buddhism, or Hinduism. No, it's conditions on the ground that lead to violence.
- As for 99% of terrorist groups being Muslim see this: [All Terrorists are Muslims…Except the 94% that Aren’t](http://www.loonwatch.com/2010/01/not-all-terrorists-are-muslims/)
- **Burning people alive** is categorically **prohibited in Islam** and is not done by Muslims as a general practice. You're (again) making the mistake of conflating the actions of **one group of people (ISIS)** who are fighting for political reasons, **not religious**, with all Muslims.
- What is this about making every woman wear the hijab? Non-Muslims are not obligated to wear hijab, even in a Muslim country, and plenty of Muslim women don't wear hijab, and the women that do are not forced to.
- Some Muslims believe a lot of things. I know someone who believes that if you carry around an onion, you won't get heatstroke. Why do you unquestioningly accept their views as being representative of the majority or of the religion?

Islam is about the worship of our Creator, yours and mine, who sent Messengers to tell us about Him, to tell us to do good and stay away from bad, to repent for our sins and to aspire for Heaven. I invite you to learn more about Islam.

Comment: Sorry but i will never visit any Muslim countries, i'm a proudly gay and i'm not putting my life at risk, but i'm ok with Muslims in their countries, just don't think you have any right to come to my land, my country, my city and think you can come judge me or you know go kill some people in a marketplace or something like that...and if you suggest that are "groups" of bad Muslims and good Muslims but i never heard of groups of Muslims to fight back against Islamic State or for their brothers in cities occupied by terrorists? I never heard about muslims protesting for woman rights or etc?

Comment: Right know many of us western societies are now being forced to debate what we should do with the refugees that are flooding our countries ( let's not forget that the reason they are coming is fleeing from Muslims terrorists and many of them even are Muslims too!) and cases of Muslims families that had come here, and their children grows up to be lured to terrorist groups is troubling...they talk about peace and love, but their beliefs and acts cannot lead to peace, but to war and things like nazism

Comment: Well you're free to keep your bigoted views :) I (and almost all other Muslims) also think it's a major crime and terrorist act to kill people in any marketplace. If you haven't heard of Muslims condemning terrorist acts in the name of Islam, have you considered the possibility you haven't looked? See [here](http://www.beliefnet.com/columnists/commonwordcommonlord/2014/08/think-muslims-havent-condemned-isis-think-again.html) As for fighting back, you have to understand the dynamics of who "fights", what for, who gets money for what, from who, etc. It isn't as simple as you may think.

Comment: @antimuslim Answer edited to answer edits to question.

Answer (score 0):

@antimuslim, as a short explanation about a part of your question, you ought to notice that: most Muslims (as real Muslims) like to live in peace, but a limited malicious group of Muslim (which we should not call them as the representative of Muslims), they are stipendiary of some enemy countries of Islam who protect them to do some acts as you see. Such as attack to some other Islamic countries (by excuse...), or doing some similar acts in order to showing Islam as a rough religion otherwise the real Islam is peace seeker.

On the other hand, if you see that some Islamic countries are fighting, in truth they are defending their land against the enemies who are protects indeed by the leading and helping of Islam’s enemy (directly or indirectly).

**Consequently**, it is not fair to call Islam and Muslims as what you named them.